# Exclude source file in compilation using Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

Is it possible to exclude a source file in the compilation process using wildcard function in a Makefile?

Like have several source files,

```
src/foo.cpp
src/bar.cpp
src/...
```

Then in my makefile I have,

```
SRC_FILES = $(wildcard src/*.cpp)
```

But I want to exclude the bar.cpp. Is this possible?

Answer (score 170):

If you're using GNU Make, you can use [`filter-out`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html):

```
SRC_FILES := $(wildcard src/*.cpp)
SRC_FILES := $(filter-out src/bar.cpp, $(SRC_FILES))
```

Or as one line:

```
SRC_FILES = $(filter-out src/bar.cpp, $(wildcard src/*.cpp))
```

Comment: New to `Makefile`s? So after reading this excellent answer go look up the difference between `=` and `:=` (both used above), and find out, why you'll usually want to use `:=` whenever possible!

Comment: Use `:=` when the variable's definition need to resolve others variables: ["these definitions can contain variable references which will be expanded before the definition is made"](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Setting.html#index-_003a_003d-1)

Comment: As an appendix to the comment of @TomaszGandor: See [The two Flavors of Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavors.html#Flavors) in the GNU make documentation.

Answer (score 18):

use find for it :)

```
SRC_FILES := $(shell find src/ ! -name "bar.cpp" -name "*.cpp")
```

Comment: did you mean $(shell find src/ ... )?

Answer (score 7):

You can use Makefile subst function:

```
 EXCLUDE=$(subst src/bar.cpp,,${SRC_FILES})
```

Answer (score 5):

The [Unix glob](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) pattern src/[!b]*.cpp excludes all src files that start with b.

That only would work, however, if bar.cpp is the only src file that starts with b or if you're willing to rename it to start with a unique character.

Comment: This works great when you also have to use `.SECONDEXPANSION` wildcard and pattern replacement such as `locales/%/_bundle.ftl: $$(wildcard locales/%/[!_]*.ftl)`, Thanks!

Comment: @zanona, you're welcome! I'm glad you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to add that all into one call:

`g++ -g $(filter-out excludedFile.cpp, $(wildcard *.cpp)) -o main` where the normal one would be `g++ -g *.cpp -o main`

And if you want to run it as well:

`g++ -g $(filter-out excludedFile.cpp, $(wildcard *.cpp)) -o main && ./main`