# Omit a directory for -I in C++

Tags: c++, c

I am using a third party framework in C from which my code in C++ uses the APIs. My Makefile has the base of the include files using `-Iframework_direcroty/include.`

To be able to use the API, I have included the header files of the same using

```
extern "C" 
{
    #include <subdir/file_name.h>
}
```

Now, the third party vendor has introduced an additional directory in the code base because of which I am facing a compilation break. I need to be able to say to my g++: **Don't include the files from framework_directory/include/shared directory but include the files from framework_directory/include directory**.

I couldn't find such option in g++ man page. Any ideas?

Comment: Rename your own headers / directories. You could also copy the third-party headers to a different location and omit the troublesome subdir that way, but chances are that header interdependencies will make that solution break sooner or later as well.

Comment: have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276202/exclude-source-file-in-compilation-using-makefile). It will give an idea to exclude files or directory from MakeFile.

Comment: @VikramDattu: The question is about omitting *header* files, not source files. The Makefile based solution will not work.

Comment: I don't quite get it. If you say `-Iframework_directory/include`, the compiler will find a header there and include it. Simply don't tell him (via `-I` or `-include` or similar options) to look in `framework_directory/include/shared`. If, however, a header file in `framework_directory/include` contains an `#include <shared/file.h>` directive, then you cannot avoid including that file IMHO.