# Exclude files from makefile

Tags: gcc, makefile

I have a rule in my makefile that uses a wildcard to get all .c files in the directory:

```
SRCS_ENC  = $(foreach DIR,$(SRC_ENC),$(patsubst $(DIR)/%,%,$(wildcard $(DIR)/*.c)))
```

Now I want to exclude all files with a specific suffix, e.g. "test"

```
function_test.c
function2_test.c
...
```

How can I do this in the makefile? I tried filter-out, but it did not work.

Comment: What has that question to do with CMake? Do you generate the Makefile with CMake?

Comment: No, sorry, I am using the gcc compiler.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exclude source file in compilation using Makefile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276202/exclude-source-file-in-compilation-using-makefile)

Comment: "I tried filter-out, but it did not work." Then you made a mistake with
it, which regrettably we can't see.

Answer (score 0):

Try using immediate assignment instead of deferred and do filter-out like this:

```
SRCS_ENC := $(foreach DIR,$(SRC_ENC),$(patsubst $(DIR)/%,%,$(wildcard $(DIR)/*.c)))
SRCS_ENC := $(filter-out %_test.c, $(SRCS_ENC))
```

You  can find documentation for the `GNU make` built-in string manipulation functions here: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html