# Makefile how to not remove one specific object file while remove all other object files and executable files?

Tags: shell, makefile

Right now I have this command: `rm -f *.x *.o`, which removes all the object files and executable files by calling `make clean` in my shell. But I have one specific object file, say `a.o` that I do not want to remove. How can I do this without hardcoding it? Note that I can only implement it under C90 because this is an assignment.

Comment: This is relatively easy in GNU make but challenging in traditional Makefiles. Can you accept a GNU-only answer?

Comment: Which C compiler you are using has absolutely no relevance here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exclude source file in compilation using Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276202/exclude-source-file-in-compilation-using-makefile)

Comment: @tripleee I'm calling "make clean" here to remove all files. The question you linked is about compilation.

Comment: Which command you put before the wildcard has absolutely no relevance; just put `rm` instead of `gcc`. The beef is how to create an expression which excludes one file. You'll notice that none of the answers say anything about compilation.

Comment: If you genuinely cannot figure out how to apply any of those answers to your scenario, maybe [edit] your question to explain where you are stuck, what you tried, and how it failed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, do not issue wildcard remove commands in a `clean:` rule (or any other). When the user types `make clean`, they could lose files that is not even under the control of the build system. Your build system should only clean what it builds. (That is, at least with the "regular strength" `clean` target; here we should acknowledge the widespread practice of providing  additional targets that remove editor backup files, `tags`, generated configuration materials and whatnot.)

The object files should be listed in some variable like `$(OBJS)` and should be removed using `rm -f ... $(OBJS)`.

If a certain object file is not to be removed, you can divide things:

```
DISPOSABLE_OBJS = ...
PRECIOUS_OBJS = ...
OBJS = $(DISPOSABLE_OBJS) $(PRECIOUS_OBJS)
```

Then in the `clean` rule, just remove the `$(DISPOSABLE_OBJS)`.

In GNU Make you have additional flexibilities, like `rm -f $(filter-out keep1.o keep2.o,$(OBJS))` to remove all `$(OBJS)` except `keep1.o` and `keep2.o`.